# how to set large table on next pages if contain is large with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I've added an header and a footer on my document by PdfPageEventHelper.

The document has several "large" tables populated at runtime.

I've tried to add those tables simply by "documen.Add(table)", but my header and my footer results overwritten.

I've already tried both methods to add the tables (WriteSelectedRows and document.Add(myPdfPtable).

Here is the code of the PageEventHelper for Head:

```
 public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document doc)
            {
                Phrase phrase = null;
                PdfPCell cell = null;           

                PdfPTable maintable = new PdfPTable(2);                
                maintable.TotalWidth = 500f;
                maintable.LockedWidth = true;
                maintable.SetWidths(new float[] { 50f, 400f });


                #region checklogo               
                if (IsLogo!=0)
                {
                   // code for display head like logo, etc
                }
                #endregion CheckSchoolNameandAddress

                maintable.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 50, 835, writer.DirectContent);

                Color color = new Color(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#A9A9A9"));
                DrawLine(writer, 25f,  780f, doc.PageSize.Width - 25f, 780f,color);
                DrawLine(writer, 25f, 780f, doc.PageSize.Width - 25f,  780f, color);

            }
```

Here is the code of the PageEventHelper for footer:

```
     public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document doc)
                {
                    Phrase phrase = null;
                    PdfPCell cell = null;
                    PdfPCell cell1 = null;
                    PdfPCell cell2 = null;
                    int pageN = writer.PageNumber;
                    String text = "Page " + pageN;

                    PdfPTable foootertable = new PdfPTable(3);
                    foootertable.TotalWidth = 500f;
                    foootertable.LockedWidth = true;
                    foootertable.SetWidths(new float[] { 50f, 60f, 50f });



                    #region checkprintedbyReportNamePageNo
                    if (Isfooter != 0)
                    {
                        // code for footer like pageno, etc
                    }
                    #endregion CheckprintedbyReportNamePageNo

                    foootertable.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 30,30, writer.DirectContent);
                    color = new Color(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#A9A9A9"));
                    DrawLine(writer, 25f, 32f, doc.PageSize.Width - 25f, 32f, color);
                    DrawLine(writer, 25f, 32f, doc.PageSize.Width - 25f, 32f, color);

                }
```

Table code which display on all page like reportdiaplay

```
    public ActionResult DetailReportPDF(int TempId, int ReportModuleId, string BoardStageId, string ShiftId, string ClassDivisionId, string Subjects)
        {
            try
            {
                var BaseUrl = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority, Url.Content("~"));

                IBoard board = Session["SchoolAdmin"] as IBoard;

                if (board != null)
                {
                    int yearid = 0; IYears currentyear = YearsDomain.GetCurrentYears(board.Board_Id); if (currentyear != null) yearid = currentyear.Year_Id;
                    string SchoolAddress = "";
                    string SchoolName = "";
                    string SchoolLogo = "";
                    SchoolName = board.Board_Name != null ? board.Board_Name.ToUpper() : "";
                    SchoolAddress = (board.Board_Address1 != null ? board.Board_Address1.ToUpper() + "," : "") + (board.Board_City != null ? board.Board_City + "," : "") + (board.Board_State != null ? board.Board_State + ", " : "") + (board.Board_Country != null ? board.Board_Country + " - " : "") + (board.Board_Pincode != null ? board.Board_Pincode + "." : "");
                    SchoolLogo = Session["SchoolLogo"] != null ? Session["SchoolLogo"].ToString() : "";

                    string filename = "";
                    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

                    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
                    document.SetMargins(88, 88, 80, 10f);
                    iTextSharp.text.Font NormalFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial Unicode MS,Arial", 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
                    iTextSharp.text.Font VNormalFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial Unicode MS,Arial", 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
                    iTextSharp.text.Font LARGFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial Unicode MS,Arial", 14, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);

                    using (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                    {
                        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
                        Phrase phrase = null;
                        PdfPCell cell = null;
                        PdfPTable maintable = null;
                        PdfPTable table = null;                       
                        PdfPTable secondTable = null;
                        PdfPCell TableCell = new PdfPCell();
                        PdfPCell secondTableCell = new PdfPCell();
                        secondTableCell.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
                        iTextSharp.text.Color color = null;
                        document.Open();
                        List<ReportSetLayout> lst = new List<ReportSetLayout>();
                        IReportTemplate RTD = ReportTemplateDomain.GetReportTemplateFromId(TempId);
                        string Newstr = "";

                        int IsLogo = 0;
                        string LogoSize="";
                        string LogoPosition="";
                        int IsSchoolName=0;
                        int IsSchoolAddress=0;
                        string SchoolNameSize = "";
                        string SchoolNamePosition = "";
                        string SchoolAddressSize = "";
                        string SchoolAddressPosition = "";

                        int Isfooter = 0;
                        int IsPrintedBy =0;
                        int IsReportName =0;
                        int PageNo =0;
                        string ShowPrintedBy=""; 
                        string ShowReportName ="";
                        string ShowPageNo = "";

                        IReportModule ReportModule = ReportModuleDomain.GetReportModulesFromId(ReportModuleId);
                        IBoardUserRights boarduserrights = BoardUserRightsDomain.GetBoardUserRights(board.Board_Id, "Reports", Session["BoardUserName"].ToString());
                        IBoardUser BU = BoardUserDomain.getBoardUserById(Convert.ToInt32(boarduserrights.Board_User_Id));

                        if (RTD != null)
                        {

                            #region forLogo

                            // code for get value for header logo    

                            #endregion forLogo

                            #region forschoolName&address

                                // code for get value for header address

                            #endregion forschoolName&address

                            #region forprintedbyReportNamePageNo

                            // code for get value for footer 

                            #endregion forprintedbyReportNamePageNo


                        }



                        writer.PageEvent = new Header() { SName = SchoolName, SAddress = SchoolAddress, SLogo = SchoolLogo, IsLogo=IsLogo, LogoSize = LogoSize, LogoPosition = LogoPosition ,IsSchoolName=IsSchoolName , IsSchoolAddress=IsSchoolAddress, SchoolNameSize=SchoolNameSize ,SchoolNamePosition=SchoolNamePosition,SchoolAddressSize=SchoolAddressSize,SchoolAddressPosition=SchoolAddressPosition};

                       // writer.PageEvent = new Header();
                        writer.PageEvent = new Footer(){ Isfooter=Isfooter,IsPrintedBy=IsPrintedBy,IsReportName=IsReportName,IsPageNo=PageNo,PrintedBy=ShowPrintedBy,ReportName=ShowReportName};

                        #region ReportBind

                        string Shortby = "";
                        List<string> lstformat = new List<string>();
                        List<string> lstWrap = new List<string>();                   


                        List<ReportColumnDetails> lstReportColumn = new List<ReportColumnDetails>();
                        lstReportColumn = ReportColumnDomain.GetReportColumnsFromReportModule(ReportModuleId);


                        List<IReportTemplateColumn> lstRptempcol = new List<IReportTemplateColumn>();
                        lstRptempcol = ReportTemplateColumnDomain.GetAllReportTemplateColumnbyID(TempId);

                        List<int> colindexid = new List<int>();
                        List<int> ColWidth = new List<int>();

                        foreach (var col in lstRptempcol)
                        {
                            ColWidth.Add(Convert.ToInt32(col.ColumnWidth));
                            colindexid.Add(Convert.ToInt32(col.Column_Index_Id));

                        }
                        foreach (var shortName in lstRptempcol)
                        {
                            if (shortName.Sortby == Convert.ToByte(1))
                            {
                                Shortby = lstReportColumn.Where(x => x.ColumnId == shortName.Column_Id).Select(y => y.ColumnName).FirstOrDefault();
                            }

                            if (lstReportColumn.Where(x => x.ColumnId == shortName.Column_Id).Select(y => y.ColumnName).FirstOrDefault().Contains("Date"))
                            {
                                lstformat.Add(lstReportColumn.Where(x => x.ColumnId == shortName.Column_Id).Select(y => y.ColumnName).FirstOrDefault() + "_" + shortName.Format);

                            }
                            if (lstReportColumn.Where(x => x.ColumnId == shortName.Column_Id).Select(y => y.ColumnName).FirstOrDefault().Contains("Gender"))
                            {
                                lstformat.Add(lstReportColumn.Where(x => x.ColumnId == shortName.Column_Id).Select(y => y.ColumnName).FirstOrDefault() + "_" + shortName.Format);

                            }
                            if (shortName.Wrap == Convert.ToByte(1))
                            {
                                lstWrap.Add(lstReportColumn.Where(x => x.ColumnId == shortName.Column_Id).Select(y => y.ColumnName).FirstOrDefault());
                            }



                        }



                        //string[] cols = Columns.TrimEnd(',').Split(',');
                        //string[] colsindex = ColumnsIndex.TrimEnd(',').Split(',');

                        string str = "";
                        string str1 = "";
                      //  DataTable dt = new DataTable("ReportTable");


                        if (ReportModule != null)
                        {


                            if (ReportModule.Report_Module_Name == "Teacher")
                            {


                                var items = new List<int>(new[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 });

                                string H1 = "Sr.No", H2 = "Teacher Name", H3 = "Contact No", H4 = "Address", H5 = "Gender", H6 = "Marital Status", H7 = "Join Date", H8 = "Leave Date", H9 = "Physically Challenged ", H10 = "Photo", H11 = "EmailId", H12 = "EmployeeId", H13 = "Group", H14 = "Religion", H15 = "Cast Category", H16 = "Cast", H17 = "Designation", H18 = "Service Category", H19 = "Anniversary Date", H20 = "Education";

                                #region trimdata
                                List<int> lstBoardStageId = new List<int>();
                                if (BoardStageId != "" || BoardStageId != null)
                                {
                                    string[] BSId = BoardStageId.TrimEnd(',').Split(',');



                                    for (int i = 0; i <= BSId.Count() - 1; i++)
                                    {
                                        if (BSId[i] != "")
                                            lstBoardStageId.Add(Convert.ToInt32(BSId[i]));
                                    }

                                }

                                List<int> lstShiftId = new List<int>();
                                if (ShiftId != "" || ShiftId != null)
                                {
                                    string[] ShiftIDs = ShiftId.TrimEnd(',').Split(',');



                                    for (int i = 0; i <= ShiftIDs.Count() - 1; i++)
                                    {
                                        if (ShiftIDs[i] != "")
                                            lstShiftId.Add(Convert.ToInt32(ShiftIDs[i]));
                                    }
                                }

                                List<int> lstClassDivisionId = new List<int>();
                                if (ClassDivisionId != "" || ClassDivisionId != null)
                                {
                                    string[] classDiv = ClassDivisionId.TrimEnd(',').Split(',');



                                    for (int i = 0; i <= classDiv.Count() - 1; i++)
                                    {
                                        if (classDiv[i] != "")
                                            lstClassDivisionId.Add(Convert.ToInt32(classDiv[i]));
                                    }

                                }
                                List<int> lstSubjects = new List<int>();
                                //if (Subjects != "" || Subjects != null)
                                //{
                                    string[] subjs = Subjects.TrimEnd(',').Split(',');

                                    for (int i = 0; i <= subjs.Count() - 1; i++)
                                    {
                                        if (subjs[i] != "")
                                            lstSubjects.Add(Convert.ToInt32(subjs[i]));
                                    }

                                //}


                                #endregion trimdata

                                List<ReportTecaherDetails> resultTeacher = new List<ReportTecaherDetails>();


                                resultTeacher = TeacherDomain.GetReportTeacher1(board.Board_Id, lstBoardStageId, lstShiftId, lstSubjects, lstClassDivisionId, Shortby, lstformat, yearid);

                                float[] widthArry = new float[20];
                                float widthCount = 0;



                                for (int i = 0; i < ColWidth.Count; i++)
                                {

                                    widthArry[i] = ColWidth[i];
                                    widthCount += ColWidth[i];

                                }

                                widthArry = widthArry.Where(x => x != 0).ToArray();

                                table = new PdfPTable(widthArry);
                                table.TotalWidth = 550f;
                                table.LockedWidth = true;
                                table.SetWidths(widthArry);

                                #region CheckHeaderText
                                foreach (var HeaderText in lstRptempcol)
                                {
                                    //code for headerText
                                }
                                #endregion CheckHeaderText

                                int Srno = 1;
                                int count = 0;

                                for (int a = 0; a < colindexid.Count; a = a + 1)
                                {

                                    if (colindexid.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(a.ToString())))
                                    {
                                        #region addcolumnHeadeName
                                        if (a.ToString() == Convert.ToString(0))
                                        {
                                            // dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(H1, typeof(string)));
                                            phrase = new Phrase();
                                            phrase.Add(new Chunk(H1, FontFactory.GetFont("Arial Unicode MS,Arial", 8, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK)));
                                            cell = PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
                                            cell.BorderColor = new iTextSharp.text.Color(229, 229, 229);
                                            cell.FixedHeight = 10f;
                                            table.AddCell(cell);
                                        }
                                        else if (a.ToString() == Convert.ToString(1))
                                        {
                                            // dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(H1, typeof(string)));
                                            phrase = new Phrase();
                                            phrase.Add(new Chunk(H2, FontFactory.GetFont("Arial Unicode MS,Arial", 8, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK)));
                                            cell = PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
                                            cell.BorderColor = new iTextSharp.text.Color(229, 229, 229);
                                            cell.FixedHeight = 10f;
                                            table.AddCell(cell);
                                        }
                                        // .... else if{}  same as above
                                        #endregion addcolumnHeadeName
                                    }                                    
                                }

                               document.Add(table);

                                secondTable = new PdfPTable(widthArry);
                                secondTable.TotalWidth = 550f;
                                secondTable.LockedWidth = true;
                                secondTable.SetWidths(widthArry);

                                foreach (var item in resultTeacher)
                                {


                                    #region rowadd

                                    if (colindexid.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(0)))
                                    {
                                        phrase = new Phrase();
                                        phrase.Add(new Chunk(Convert.ToString(Srno), FontFactory.GetFont("Arial Unicode MS,Arial", 8, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK)));
                                        secondTableCell = PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
                                        secondTableCell.BorderColor = new iTextSharp.text.Color(229, 229, 229);
                                        secondTableCell.FixedHeight = 50f;
                                        secondTable.AddCell(secondTableCell);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {

                                    }
                                     // .... if{} same as above
                                    #endregion rowadd
                                    Srno++;



                                }


                                document.Add(secondTable);

                            }

                        }



                        #endregion ReportBind                      

                        filename = filename + now.Hour.ToString("00") + now.Minute.ToString("00") + now.Second.ToString("00") + now.Millisecond.ToString() + now.DayOfYear.ToString("000") + now.Day.ToString("00") + now.Month.ToString("00") + now.Year.ToString("0000") + ".pdf";
                        document.Close();
                        byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                        memoryStream.Close();
                        Response.Clear();
                        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");
                        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                        Response.Buffer = true;
                        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
                        Response.End();
                        Response.Close();


                    }

                    return View();
                }
                else
                {
                    return Redirect(BaseUrl);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can try

`Image.ScaleToFitLineWhenOverflow = false;`

Refer SO Answer # [Set Pagination in Itextsharp Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22755787/auto-paging-with-itextsharp)